# Handle <video> tag fullscreen

Tags: electron, video.js

Three years ago a user asked about this. I'm developing an Electron app. The app runs at fullscreen, but I cannot use fullscreen for video and the app at the same time. This is what the user asked [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/handle-video-tag-fullscreen/55998):

> Now electron supports fullscreen by actually fullscreen the whole app.
>
> I wonder if there is any way to handle requestFullscreen differently
> so that the video takes all the space of the window, but the window
> itself doesn’t change.

This problem made me open [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66658020/make-a-video-js-component-fullscreen-using-electron-and-vue) stackoverflow post, so the answer to this question would solve the post's one.

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? Are you seeking solutions to the other question you've linked? That'd be a duplicate question, then.

Comment: No, I'm just asking the same question that person did some years ago in other forum, just that.

Answer (score 1):

The player has `enterFullWindow()` and `exitFullWindow()` methods which cause the player to fit to the window.